# Que debo hacer para que se ejecute una consulta asíncrona en mi app Flask con Python

Tags: python, flask, asyncio

Ahora estoy aprendiendo **Python**.

Que debo hacer para que se ejecute una consulta asíncrona a mi base de datos desde una ruta especifica en mi **app Flask Python_**

Este es el error que recibo>

```
En el browser>
{
  "routeTest | Server Message": "Error en la solicitud: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'run_until_complete'"
}
```

En la consola de python.

```
routeStar
controllerStar
moduleStar
RegistersModel | Error en la consulta: Task <Task pending name='Task-4' coro=<AsyncToSync.main_wrap() running at C:\Users\... 

***attached to a different loop***

controllerDone
```

Esto lo último que intente antes de consultar en este portal.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import asyncio

app = Flask(__name__)
    
# Importa la función de inicialización de la base de datos desde db_core.py
from db.db_core import * 

# Importa archivo de rutas principales
from routes.index_route import *

# simulando conexion y consulta BASE DATOS..
async def dataBase():
    print ('star fetching to dataBase')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('done fetching to dataBase')
    return {'data:': 1}

# simulando un MODELADO
class RegistersModel:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    async def get_all_registers(self):
        print('moduleStar')
        try:
            query = "SELECT * FROM registros"
            result = await db.fetch_data(query)
            print('moduleDone')
            return result
        except Exception as e:
            print('RegistersModel | Error en la consulta:', str(e))
            return []
                    
# simulando un CONTROLADOR
model= RegistersModel()

class RegistersController:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
            
    async def readAllData(self):
        print ('controllerStar')
        try:
            result = await model.get_all_registers()
            print('controllerDone')
            return result
        except Exception as e:
            print('RegistersController | Error en la consulta:', str(e))
            return []

# simulando un ROUTE
controller = RegistersController()

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
async def test():
    try:
        print('routeStar')
        data =  await controller.readAllData()
        result =  asyncio.run_until_complete(data)
        #result =  asyncio.run( await controller.readAllData() )
        #result =  await loop.run_until_complete(controller.readAllData())
        print('routeDone')
            
        # Formatea los resultados como JSON y los envía como respuesta
        return jsonify(result)
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"routeTest | Server Message": f"Error en la solicitud: {str(e)}"}), 500

CORS(app)

# Función para inicializar la base de datos asincrónica
async def init_db():
    await initialize_db()

# Pruebas por fuera de utilizar las rutas...
""" async def consultar_datos():
    query = "SELECT * FROM registros"
    try:
        resultados = await db.fetch_data(query)
        for fila in resultados:
            print(fila)
        #print(resultados)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error al consultar la base de datos:', str(e)) """
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(init_db())
    #loop.run_until_complete(consultar_datos())
    #loop.run_until_complete(controller.readAllData())
        
    # Ejecuta la aplicación Flask en modo asíncrono
    #app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, threaded=False)
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

---

( caprilo: Si, ese era el error.. )

Sin embargo, indagando Flask tiene su propio manejador de eventos y con lo que estaba intentando chocaba con asyncio.

Entonces ajuste el código para solo utilizar Flask como el manejador de eventos asíncronos.

al realizar la petición he podido mostrar los datos en el browser pero si intento nuevamente ya no me los muestra y recibo estos mensajes de error:

En la consola del browser:

```
- No recibo errores.
```

En la consola de VSCode:

RegistersModel | Error en la consulta: Event loop is closed
C:_Datos\Proyectos\NegLinea\netPanal\netpanal.app\app2.py:117: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Pool._wakeup' was never awaited
return []

Este es el código:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify, redirect, url_for
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
# import asyncio
import tracemalloc
tracemalloc.start(25)

app = Flask(__name__)

CORS(app)

# Importa archivo de rutas principales
from routes.index_route import *

# Importa la función de inicialización de la base de datos desde db_core.py
from db.db_core import * 

# Función para inicializar la base de datos asincrónica
async def init_db():
    await initialize_db()

# Decorador personalizado para ejecutar la inicialización de la base de datos antes de la primera solicitud
def before_first_request(func):
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        await init_db()
        return await func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

# simulando un MODELADO
class RegistersModel:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    async def get_all_registers(self):
        try:
            query = "SELECT * FROM registros"
            data = await db.fetch_data(query)
            return data
        except Exception as e:
            print('RegistersModel | Error en la consulta:', str(e))
            return []
                    
# simulando un CONTROLADOR
model = RegistersModel()

class RegistersController:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
            
    async def readAllData(self):
        try:
            data = await model.get_all_registers()
            return data
        except Exception as e:
            print('RegistersController | Error en la consulta:', str(e))
            return []

# simulando un ROUTE
controller = RegistersController()

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
@before_first_request
async def test():
    try:
        data = await controller.readAllData()
        return jsonify(data)
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"routeTest | Server Message": f"Error en la solicitud: {str(e)}"}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Ejecuta la aplicación Flask en modo asíncrono
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

Comment: El módulo `asyncio` no tiene un método `run_until_complete`. Este es un método de un obtenido a través de `asyncio.new_event_loop()`.